# How to insert an UIView (during launch time) that will be used for Core Animation after in the program?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, core-animation, calayer, exc-bad-access

I have a View based application for iPhone/iPod that plays audio, having a VU meter showing the input dB level. This VU meter is animated using Core Animation.

The app runs fine, with the VU meter working great, having just one single View. But now, sadly, that I have inserted a Tab bar controller, to have another View with some internet content, I can't get the VU meter to work on my first View, as before.

The app crashes (receiving the  **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** message) because the UIView (that contains the VU meter .png file for Core Animation) is not being properly inserted during launching time as it did before as a View only application.

Here is my code, in the **myAppDelegate.m** file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

{

```
PlayerViewController *newController = [[PlayerViewController  alloc] initWithNibName: @"PlayerView"
                                                                        bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
self.viewController = newController; 
[newController release];

UIView *controllerView = [self.viewController view]; 
[self.window addSubview: controllerView];
[self.viewController addBargraphToView: controllerView];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; 


 self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

}

And here is my **PlayerViewController.m** file, where I have the **addBargraphToView**  method containing my image to be inserted. It remains invisible until the VU meter starts working:

```
- (void) addBargraphToView: (UIView *) parentView {

// static image for showing average level
UIImage *soundbarImage      = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"vu-meter.png"] retain];


// background colors for generated image for showing peak level
self.peakClear              = [UIColor clearColor]; 
self.peakGray               = [UIColor lightGrayColor];  
self.peakOrange             = [UIColor orangeColor];  
self.peakRed                = [UIColor redColor];  

levelMeter                  = [CALayer layer];
levelMeter.anchorPoint      = CGPointMake (0.0, 20.0);                      // anchor to halfway up the left edge
levelMeter.frame            = CGRectMake (15, 200, 0, kLevelMeterHeight);   // set width to 0 to start to completely hide the bar graph segements
levelMeter.contents         = (UIImage *) soundbarImage.CGImage;

peakLevelMeter              = [CALayer layer];
peakLevelMeter.frame        = CGRectMake (41, 233, 0, kLevelMeterHeight);
peakLevelMeter.anchorPoint  = CGPointMake (0.5, 10.0);
peakLevelMeter.backgroundColor = peakGray.CGColor;

peakLevelMeter.bounds       = CGRectMake (0, 0, 0, kLevelMeterHeight);
peakLevelMeter.contentsRect = CGRectMake (0, 0, 1.0, 1.0);

[parentView.layer addSublayer: levelMeter];
[parentView.layer addSublayer: peakLevelMeter];

[soundbarImage release];
```

}

How can I solve this problem? Should I insert the UIView image at some other point, and not during the application's launch time?

Many thanks for your help, dear friends!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this call:

```
[self.viewController addBargraphToView: controllerView];
```

To **-viewDidLoad** inside your PlayerViewController implementation:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addBargraphToView: self.view];
}
```

**Edit**

OK, I think the problem lies in double adding viewControllers. Make this the content of your **application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:** method:

```
PlayerViewController *newController = [[PlayerViewController  alloc] initWithNibName: @"PlayerView"
                                                                        bundle: [NSBundle mainBundle]]; 
self.viewController = newController;
[newController release];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: newController, yourInterntContenViewController, nil];

[self.window addSubview: self.tabBarController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

Comment: Hi Bartosz, thanks for your answer! But the app still crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. I'm thinking that the line self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController overrides any further call on the view, because when it's not there the VU meter works, but the Tab Bar doesn't show up. Do you any any other suggestion?

Comment: Dear Bartosz, now thanks to you I have the TabBar showing at the bottom of my screen, with no crashes and the VU meter woking as it should. Now another issue: this internet content on the second view is of class UINavigationController, that is not pushing the web browsers any more. What can I do to make then work properly again? Many THANKS!

Comment: It's really hard to say without seeing the code and my glass ball got crashed by demons recently... ;(

Comment: Lets try to fix the glass ball... lol... I think that the TaBarController that I've already setup on the MainWindow.xib is not the one being called in myAppDelegate.m file. As I see, when we alloc and initialize PlayerViewController on myAppDelegate.m it goes on top of my already made TabBarController. I know that is so vague, but what part of the code would like to take a closer look?

Comment: Actually everything is OK, because we are setting the viewControllers explicitly ourselves, so it's obvious that any properties that were loaded from .xib are gone. It appears to me that you've got some mess caused by changing your mind on what should be application's main view controller. Here's my suggestion: make a new project, UITabBarNavigationController based one and set up your controllers in .xib. You can reuse 99% of your code and you will avoid those problems you have right now. That seems reasonable for me, since no one is going to fix whole program for you ;)

Comment: I was thinking about that and your word came right on time. Thanks a lot and I'll let you know how things went. You've been of great help to me !!!

Comment: Thanks Bartosz! I did as you suggested and now everything is fine, as it should be. Your code suggestions were of GREAT help to me. Regards!

Comment: I just would like you to know that I loved Portaball! I'm buying the full version now, writing a review on it ;-)